# how to make parent method to be called using $this->methodName in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

I have two classes. One is parent and another is child. Both have a same name method. The problem is that parent method does not get called using $this->methodName.

**Parent class**

```
class Parent
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->init();
    }

    // this function never get executed and why?
    public function init()
    {

       //do something

    }
}
```

**The Child class**

```
class Child extends Parent
{

   public function __construct()
   {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->init();
   }

   public function init()
   {
   // do something different
   }
}
```

How to call the parent method without using parent::init?

Comment: why is your child class not extending the parent class?

Comment: I have corrected it. I did not type it.

Comment: Why would you not use parent::init ?

Comment: Having both a constructor and an init function is a bad idea, due to the parent child issue you're running into here.  If at all possible you should have just the constructor (though if a constructor is doing anything at all other than initialising variables then it's probably trying to do too much)

Comment: @GordonM Thanks. I'd like to know where do you do the initial calling part? I am doing all calling in init method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `self` to refer to the current class. As opposed to `$this`, which refers to the current object at runtime.

```
class ParentClass
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        self::init();
    }

    public function init()
    {   
        echo 'parent<br/>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        self::init();
    }
?>
```

Additionaly in Parent class use also self to avoid executing parent init and child init.

Comment: I don't see any static function called `init` in that class, do you?

Comment: @AlonEitan function don't have to be static for you to use self.

Comment: @AndreFerraz Can you please provide a reference?

Comment: See no point. You don't need static function to run it through self::. I don't see static function __construct() in that class, do you?

Comment: Run this:

<?php
 
 class Mom{
  public function __construct(){
   self::init();
  }
 
  public function init(){
   echo 'mom init';
  }
 }
 
 class Son extends Mom{
  public function __construct(){
   parent::__construct();
   self::init();
  }
 
  public function init(){
   echo 'son init';
  }
 }
 
 $foo = new Son();

Comment: @AlonEitan just create a class with a method that is not static and call it via self::method and you'll see you don't need a static method to use self.

Comment: @Maytyn The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) states that you use `self` for static method, but since I have tested your code and it worked, i'll remove my downvote (Although this doesn't answer the OP question). I'll even upvote to admit my mistake

Comment: Plus the documentation does not static that .. "is a token that allows access to static, constant, and overridden properties or methods of a class.", it says methods not static methods

Comment: @AndreFerraz Thanks for clearing that out for me - I still don't think this answer provide a solution to the question (which is weird and  unclear), but I did removed my downvote

Comment: @AlonEitan Actually it does. If author will operate on self:: and parent:: it will work fine, when he calls parent::_construct in Child, and in Parent _construct there will be self::init().

Comment: @Maytyn So, although it's true,  it break the whole idea of polymorphism

Answer (score 0):

The thing is `parent::` is there for a reason and one of those reason is to deal with the "problem" (which is not a problem) you have.

Obviously if you have a child class with a function called e.g `myfunction()` and a parent class with a function called `myfunction()`, if you use `$this->myfunction()` in the child it will obvious call the child's `myfunction()` function because `$this` is a reference to the current object.

There is no harm in using `parent`, it is there for a reason.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a solution that will enable me to run Parent class independent.